# Is there a way to store mail attachments outside of mailboxes?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, data

Nowadays, size limits on mail attachments are less comprehensible by traditional users. I am looking for a way to extract mail attachments as simple files that I would be able to manage elsewhere.

On technical side, I could be able to raise significantly size limits if I were able to store files attached to mail on a dedicated server. I would then be able to clean them after 6 months, for instance.

Do you know a way to do this with open source Linux software ?

Comment: Any random web server software running on a publicly accessible host should be able to do this.

Comment: Maybe I was'nt clear enough in my question. I am searching how can I do this with postfix or exim, for instance. I haven't seen any mean to separate attachments from mail.

Comment: So this is about storing more messages within a given maximum *mailbox* size, not working around an insufficient maximum mail *message* size?

Comment: Please take a look at this [how-to](https://kuther.net/howtos/howto-receive-mail-and-save-attachment-fetchmail-procmail-and-metamail)

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer: [LightAttachment](https://code.google.com/p/lightattachment/)

According to their website:

> LightAttachment is a Postfix content filter designed to extract large attachment files from mails, saved them to a data server and replace them by a link into the mails

That's exacty what I was looking for ! I'll be to send those files to an other server and manage them as files, not as mailboxes.